# Rails won't accept namespace in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm following instructions on the Social Streams github wiki to add in a new model to an application using the Social Streams engine. The instructions are here: 
https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/How-to-add-new-activity-types

When I attempt to add this line to my model:

```
include SocialStream::Modules::Object
```

I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant SocialStream::Modules
```

I think I am missing something fundamental here.

My model code is:

```
class MediaCatagory < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SocialStream::Modules::Object
  attr_accessible :activity_object_id, :description, :media_cat, :seq, :version
end
```

**EDIT**
I guess I should ask where should I start looking when getting an error on an include?

Comment: you did the rake install and restarted?

Comment: I did restart the web server. rake install is giving me an error: Don't know how to build task 'install'

Comment: you followed the install instructions: https://github.com/ging/social_stream#installation ?

Comment: Yes. The application is working fine, and I am able to change the templates, but am now trying to add a new model. I have run rake db:migrate and the new table has been created in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much to my surprise I found the problem went away after I rebooted my machine. I had previously restarted the webserver several times but had not rebooted.

I don't understand what is happening here: some type of weird caching?